# Why does free energy density in Ginzburg-Landau have a term $h^2/(8\pi)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, thermodynamics, phase-transition, superconductivity

I've been studying introductory theory about superconductor, and then encountered the 'free energy' of Ginzburg-Landau theory which is going to be minimized:
$$F_S(r)=F_N(r)-\alpha|\psi|^2+\frac{1}{2}\beta|\psi|^4+\frac{1}{2m}\left|\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\triangledown-q\frac{A}{c}\right)\psi\right|^2+\frac{h^2}{8\pi}$$
What I don't understand is these two:

1. How can such microscopic field $h=\triangledown\times A$ be used in a mean field theory? In particular, why $h^2/8\pi$ is used instead of $H^2/8\pi$? ($h$ is microscopic field, and $H$ is macroscopic H-field averaged in suitable range.)
2. Why magnetic energy is in the form of $\frac{h^2}{8\pi}$, not $-\int M\cdot dH_{ext}$ as one normally calculate Helmholtz free energy of normal and superconducting state? (Actually Charles Kittel's book introduced the theory in latter term, while most of textbook uses $h^2/8\pi$

Right now I'm guessing that:

1. The order parameter $\psi(r)$ is mean field of stochastic behaviror, and it is average of freedom, not spatial variation. So this parameter is spatially microscopic one, thus agreeing with use of microscopic field.
2. Indeed the 'free field' $F$ in Ginzburg-Landau theory is a phenomenological one, so it doesn't have to coincide with Helmholtz free energy. In thermodynamics, the work done by external current source can be either included or excluded depending on whether the system of interest involves external source. The magnetic energy becomes $-\int M\cdot dH_{ext}$ when one excludes contribution of external source. However, in G-L theory, one does calculus of variation, finding configuration that minimizes given 'free energy' respect to variation $\delta\psi$ and $\delta A$, so it doesn't matter whether one includes constant contribution of external field source. Then the therm $h^2/8\pi$ can be interpreted as magnetic energy including external contribution.

I'm not sure about this whole argument. Can anyone advise me about this problem?

Comment: $h$ is a magnetic field. Why do you say it's a microscopic quantity? $\frac{h^2}{8\pi}$ is simply the energy stored in a magnetic field, in appropriate units.

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə I was hesitated about what h exactly means, because when one tries to derive current equation by regarding variation $\delta A$, it is necessary to write  $h=\triangledown\times A$. I thought that if h is a macroscopic field H, then $\triangledown\cdot H=-\triangledown\cdot M \neq 0$, so it would be impossible to represent H with curl of such vector potential... What am I missing here?

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə I also thought about the possibility the last term is just $B^2/8\pi$ with B-field $B=\triangledown\times A$, but I wonder if this form is appropriate. $B^2/8\pi$ includes energy maintaining current loop against change in B field, which is appropriate in classical electrodyamics with Amperian loop model. However, in current situation, the energy necessary for external current is usually excluded when one investigate intrinsic energy of material itself, and the energy necessary for supercurrent is nonsense since it is a quantum-mechanical effect...

Comment: $h$ is indeed just $B$, regardless how you call it. The spirit of Landau and Ginzburg is to simply build a theory of $\psi$ and $A$ respecting all the symmetries. The way to do that is to write all these harmless potential terms for $\psi$, the kinetic term for $\psi$, which you covariantise to preserve gauge invariance and lastly you need to add a kinetic term for $A$. This is precisely $B^2= h^2 =|\!|\nabla\times A|\!|^2$.

Comment: In a geometric language, $(\nabla-\#A)\psi =: \mathrm{D}_A\psi$ and $``B\text{''} = F =: \mathrm{d}A$.